# Vasicek interest rate of T-forward measure

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, quantitative

I know dr of risk-neutrual measure is

[image]

There is a price of a pure-discount bond can be derived by computing the expectation, I get:
[image]

where A and B are:
[image]

why dr becomes to:

[image]

under T-forward measure?

Comment: Girsanov theorem. $W^T$ is the BM under the $T$-forward measure that has Radon-Nikodym density $$\frac{\exp(-\int_0^Tr(t)dt)}{P(0,T)}$$ w.r.t. risk-neutral measure.

Answer (score 0):

The two BMs in the risk-neutral and $T$-forward measures are related by
$$ dW(t) = dW^T(t) + \sigma_P dt, $$
where $\sigma_P$ is the volatility of the zero-coupon bond $P(t,T)$. This is because $P(t,T)$ is the numeraire of the $T$-forward measure.

Because the volatility of $P(t,T)$ is $\sigma_P = -\sigma B(t,T)$, you get the result:
$$ dr(t) = \big(k\theta - \sigma^2 B(t,T) - k r(t)\big)dt + \sigma dW^T(t).
$$